# How to run pptpd in coreos?

Tags: linux-kernel, coreos, pptp

I'm trying to run `pptpd` container on a CoreOS system.
But I cannot load ppp kernel modules.
CoreOS doesn't allow me create directory.
Is it possible to install the missing modules?

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=CoreOS
DISTRIB_RELEASE=681.2.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME="Red Dog"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="CoreOS 681.2.0"

# ls /lib/modules/4.0.5/kernel/drivers/net/ppp
ls: cannot access /lib/modules/4.0.5/kernel/drivers/net/ppp: No such file or directory

# mkdir /lib/modules/4.0.5/kernel/drivers/net/ppp
mkdir: cannot create directory '/lib/modules/4.0.5/kernel/drivers/net/ppp': Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPP support was only recently enabled in CoreOS: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/pull/1606

I don't believe it has landed in the alpha release channel yet but it should be available within weeks.